# Search a particular string in XML file using Stax

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, string-parsing, stax

I'm trying to check whether particular 2 strings are present in an XML file or not.

The xml code

```
<datapoint nature="PARAMETRIC" division="COLL_COMP_ENG" programmaticName="t_val_calc_enrg_accumulated" />
<datapoint nature="PARAMETRIC" division="COLL_COMP_ENG" programmaticName="t_val_calc_pwr_consumed" />
```

Java code..

```
    Integer count=0;
    XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
     XMLStreamReader rdr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("E:\\SVN\\MasterData\\MasterData.xml"));

      while (rdr.hasNext()) {
      if (rdr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
      if (rdr.getLocalName().equals("datapoint")) {
           String txt = rdr.getAttributeValue("programmaticName");
            if (txt.indexOf("t_val_calc_pwr_consumed") > 0 || txt.indexOf("t_val_calc_enrg_accumulated") > 0) {
              System.out.println(txt);
              count++;
            }
       }
  }
  }
System.out.println(count);
```

Whenever i try to run the code i get an error message   "String cannot be converted to int" for the line.

```
  String txt = rdr.getAttributeValue("programmaticName");
```

The stacktrace is

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader.getAttributeValue
at sample.eXTRACT.main(eXTRACT.java:42)
     Java Result: 1
     BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

The expected output:

```
   t_val_calc_enrg_accumulated
   t_val_calc_pwr_consumed
```

Comment: Can you please provide the complete error stack trace.

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`XMLStreamReader#getAttributeValue` takes an `int` as the index of the attribute as an argument (e.g. in this case, `rdr.getAttributeValue(2)`).

You are parametrizing it with a single `String`, which will not compile.

Alternatively to an `int`-based attribute order indexing, you can use the overload: `getAttributeValue(String namespaceURI, String localName)`

API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html).

Comment: so will the line be "txt = rdr.getAttributeXXX("programmaticName");" ??

Comment: @Lucy obviously not since there is no `getAttributeValue` method available taking a single `String` argument.